# Locating windows .exe equavalent files in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, filesystems

I am trying to use the Files tool as much as i can, since I am still new to the Linux filesystem.

Something i find quite annoying as a previous Windows user, is that there seems to be no obvious equavalent to .exe files in Ubuntu? I get that every file is executable, but is there no way to pinpoint the .exe files that are executing the software which folder you are looking into?

Comment: The thing is, compiled files in unix OSes don’t have extensions. You can find the equivalent to `C:\Windows\System32` in `/bin/` and `/usr/bin`

Comment: To find the location of files from the terminal, use `type (program name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, not "every file is executable".  Files have metadata associated with them, and one piece of that metadata includes whether or not it is executable.  One way to examine that metadata is with the `ls` command:

```
$ ls -l
total 12
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ownerName groupName  4 Mar 20 18:01 executableFile
   ^  ^  ^
```

I don't want to delve too deeply into permissions, but those
x's indicate that the file is executable, from right-to-left,
by the user `ownerName`, by anyone in the `groupName` group,
or by anyone else.  Often the `ownerName` and `groupName` will be
`root`, so the third `x` will be the one you'd likely be most
interested in in the short term.

What executable is run when you type a command?  Much like with Windows, there's a environment variable named PATH that contains a set of directories in which the shell (the command interpreter) will look for executable files with the name that you provide.  Windows uses `;` as a directory delimiter, Linux (and Unix is general) uses `:`.  You can use the `echo` command to print the content of that variable:

```
$ echo $PATH
/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin...
```

You can use the `which` command to identify the full path of a command:

```
$ which ls
/usr/bin/ls
```

As @Stan Strum mentioned in a comment above, you can also use the `type` command:

```
$ type ls
ls is hashed (/usr/bin/ls)
```